# Ingresar codigo ascii dentro de comillas c++

Tags: c++, string, ascii

podrian decirme como insertar codigos **ascii** dentro de `""`?

Por ejemplo insertar 3(decimal) que en ascii significa **End of text** dentro de `char asd = ""`.

O dentro de `string asd = ""`

Y tambien vi que se usa `\n` para saltar una linea pero el codigo ascii para eso es 10(decimal) entonces porque se usa `\n`? Hay otros **\algo** que signifiquen codigos ascii? Gracias, no pude encontrar esto en ninguna parte

Answer (score 2):

Para insertar 3 en decimal (que es igual a 03 en hexadecimal) usarías `"\x03"`
Los códigos de escape en C++ son :

```
Secuencia 
de Escape Descripción      Representación
   \'     comilla simple    byte 0x27 codificado ASCII
   \"     doble comilla     byte 0x22 codificado ASCII
   \?     interrogante      byte 0x3f codificado ASCII
   \\     barra invert.     byte 0x5c codificado ASCII
   \a     campana sonora    byte 0x07 codificado ASCII
   \b     borrar atrás      byte 0x08 codificado ASCII
   \f     alimentación      byte 0x0c codificado ASCII
          formulario - nueva página     
   \n     alimentación      byte 0x0a codificado ASCII 
         de linea - nueva página      
   \r     retorno de carro  byte 0x0d codificado ASCII  
   \t     tabulador         byte 0x09 codificado ASCII 
         horizontal        
   \v     tabulador         byte 0x0b codificado ASCII
         vertical          
   \nnn   cualquier valor   byte nnn 
         octal             
   \xnn   cualquier valor   byte nn
         hexadecimal          
   \unnnn nombre universal  code point U+nnnn
         de carácter(*)     
   \Unnnnnnnn nombre        code point U+nnnnnnnn 
         universal de caracter(*)
```

(*) Estos son códigos unicode. Y pueden generar varios caracteres.

Traducido de [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) bajo licencia [Creative Commons Attribution-Sharealike 3.0 Unported License](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Copyright/CC-BY-SA)

Answer (score 0):

*podrian decirme como insertar codigos ascii dentro de ""?*

si a dentro de comillas se referie algo asi:

- `std::string dentro_de_comillas_1 = "\\n";`

o asi:

- `dentro_de_comillas += (char)test;`

---

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int test = 10; // -> \n en ascii

  std::string dentro_de_comillas = "dentro_de_comillas";
  dentro_de_comillas += (char)test;

  std::cout << dentro_de_comillas;
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? " << (char)test;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

  std::string dentro_de_comillas_1 = "\\n";
  std::cout << dentro_de_comillas;
  std::cout << "What is your name? " << (char)test;
}
```

stdout:

```
dentro_de_comillas
What is your name? 
Hello, !
dentro_de_comillas
What is your name?
```

Test <kbd>[Ideone](http://ideone.com/d19DKM)</kbd>

---

*es 10(decimal) entonces porque se usa `\n`?*

si entiendo bien esa parte se usa `\n` para que puede usarlo dentro de un string por ejemplo, puede ver debajo como se comporta con `\n` y con `10` en algunos casos, espero le ayude.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{



  std::cout << "What is your name? \n";
  std::cout << "What is your name?" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "---" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "What is your name? 10";
  std::cout << "What is your name?" << (char)10;
  std::cout << "What is your name? (char)10";
  std::cout << "What is your name?";
}
```

stdout:

```
What is your name? 
What is your name?
---
What is your name? 10What is your name?
What is your name? (char)10What is your name?
```